# Find index of nth occurence of 1 in binary vector (matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, binary

I have a binary vector like this `x = [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]`. I want to find the index of lets say the 7th 1, which is 9.

I know I can do this:

```
y = find(x);
index = y(7);
```

But what if the vector is huge and I want to conserve memory usage? Wouldn't `y = find(x)` use alot of memory? If so, is there any way around this?

I am using this as an alternate way of storing indexes for nonbasis and basis elements in a linear programming problem. So I would like to avoid storing the indices as numerical values.

Would the following be a good solution?

```
basis = [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
basisIndex = 7;
correctIndex = getIndex(basisIndex, basis); % should be 9 when basisIndex = 7

function ret = getIndex(basisIndex, basis) 
    counter = 1;
    for value = find(basis) % iterate through [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        if counter == basisIndex
            ret = value;
            break;
        end
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: I added some information at the end of the question. I was thinking that saving the values returned by find would take away the advantage of storing the indices in a binary vector.

Comment: @SardarUsama I was thinking that the function I added would conserve memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through `x`. First, it will not create a new vector `y=find(x)` (save memory). Second, if `basisIndex` is small, it will be more efficient.

Suppose `x` is a 1e8 by 1 vector. Let's compare `find` with just iteration.

```
basis = randi(2,1e8,1) - 1;
basisIndex = 7;

tic % your first method
y = find(basis);
index = y(basisIndex);
toc

tic % iterate through base
index = 1;
match = 0;
while true
    if basis(index)
        match = match + 1;
        if match == basisIndex
            break
        end
    end
    index = index + 1;     
end 
toc
```

Output

```
Elapsed time is 1.214597 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000061 seconds.
```

Even if the `basisIndex` is large

```
basisIndex = 5e7;
```

The result from iteration is still more efficient

```
Elapsed time is 1.250430 seconds. % use find
Elapsed time is 0.757767 seconds. % use iteration
```